# Changing a float to an integer in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a Cash Register code. And i would like my output to carry the cents into the dollars such as this

```
input:3.20
input:17.50
ouput:20.70
the output i want:2070
```

If you would like for me to post the code it is being used in just ask

Comment: I'm sorry, but asking how to multiply by 100 in python is kind of... no, I don't know the word...

Comment: I apolgize for not instantly knowing how to change a float output to a int. since I was confused about the print my professor had in the test function of print("%.2f"%value). You shouldn't post redundant comments.

Comment: If you don't know it, you can at least put some effort into using the resources which are already there: https://www.google.com.au/#q=python+float+to+int

Answer (score 0):

I'd be looking at the formula:

```
int (value * 100)
```

See the following transcript for proof-of-concept:

```
pax> python

Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 16:53:07) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> value1 = 3.20

>>> value2 = 17.50

>>> value = value1 + value2

>>> print value
20.7

>>> print int (value * 100)
2070

>>> _
```